# Not able to run Cassandra server on Ubuntu . Permission Denied error

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-10.10

I am able to setup cassandra on ubuntu but when executing following command 
paranjai is the user

*paranjai@ubuntu:~$ /etc/init.d/cassandra start*

Following error is received

cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied Cannot set group id for user ‘cassandra’
Error validating user ‘cassandra’
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/cassandra.pid: Permission denied

any help is appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sudo:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cassandra start
```